# Unable to find installed file nvidia.icd (No such file or directory) in Ubuntu

Tags: nvidia, gpu, 21.10

I have posted the question before but didn't get much help and I have tried every proposed solution there is online but I couldn't get my Nvidia driver to work properly.
I had no idea what was the cause until I came across this [question in Nvidia forums](https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/nvidia-driver-is-not-loaded-ubuntu-18-10/70495/240)
I ran the nvidia-bug-report.sh command and after going through the log file the first thing I noticed was the line that says:

```
Unable to find installed file '/etc/OpenCL/vendors/nvidia.icd' (No such file or directory).
```

I tried searching for this error but couldn't find anything useful.
I istalled my driver after running this command `ubuntu-drivers devices` and making sure to install the recommended driver which is `nvidia-driver-470` I also installed cuda toolkit. But why am I not getting Nvidia properly installed?
Since I can't attache a file here I'm sharing a doc containing all the bug report
https://docs.google.com/document/d/1_JK835hI-BLvZgqDolm2TuaAKIymq0AXSfaOKvW0-9M/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: You have to install one of the relevant [`libnvidia-compute-…`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=impish&arch=amd64&mode=exactfilename&searchon=contents&keywords=nvidia.icd) packages.

Comment: didn't work I tried `sudo apt-get install libnvidia-compute-470`

Comment: ?Nvidia 470 ?? **418** and **495** is mentioned too  .... Quote log file: `The previously installed symlink '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLX_nvidia.so.0' has target 'libGLX_nvidia.so.495.29.05', but it was installed with target 'libGLX_nvidia.so.418.67'. ` etc. etc. similar inconsistency.